# Unable to decode Custom object at Avro Consumer end in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have a concrete class which I am Serializing in Byte array to be sent to a Kafka topic.
For serializing I am using ReflectDatumWriter .
Before sending the bytes[] I am putting schema ID in first 4 bytes with schema ID after checking some online tutorial.

I am able to send the message but while consuming it in Avro console consumer I am getting response as :

> ./bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 0:9092 --property
>   schema.stry.url=http://0:8081 --property print.key=true --topic Test

```
"1" "\u0000" 
"1" "\u0000" 
"1" "\u0000" 
"1" "\u0000" 
"1" "\u0000"
"1" "\u0000" 
"1" "\u0000" 
"1" "\u0000" 
"1" "\u0000" 
"1" "\u0000"
```

```
    MParams ddb = new MParams();
    ddb.setKey("ss");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord<String, byte[]>("Test", "1", build(1, Producer.serialize(ddb)));
        Future resp = kafkaFullAckProducer.send(record);

        System.out.println("Success" + resp.get());
    }
}

public static <T> byte[] serialize(T data) {
    Schema schema = null;
    if (data == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Data cannot be null in AvroByteSerializer");
    }
    try {
        schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(data.getClass());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DatumWriter<T> writer = new ReflectDatumWriter<T>(schema);
        writer.write(data, new EncoderFactory().directBinaryEncoder(out, null));
        byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
        return bytes;
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error serializing Avro message", e);
    }
}

public static byte[] build(Integer schemaId, byte[] data) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    out.write(0);
    try {
        out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(schemaId).array());
        out.write(data);
        byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        return bytes;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception in avro record builder , msg :" + e.getMessage());
    }



@Data
public class MParams extends MetricParams{

    // POJO version

    @Nullable
    private String key;


}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "@c")
@Union(value= {MParams.class})
public abstract class MetricParams {

}
```

Working Serializer snippet

```
public byte[] serialize(String topic, T record) {
        Schema schema;
        int id;
        try {
            schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(record.getClass());
            id = client.register(topic + "-value", schema);
        } catch (IOException | RestClientException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return serializeImpl(id, schema, record);
    }

    protected byte[] serializeImpl(int id, Schema schema, T object) throws SerializationException {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            out.write(0x0);
            out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(id).array());

            BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().directBinaryEncoder(out, null);
            DatumWriter<T> writer = new ReflectDatumWriter<T>(schema);
            writer.write(object, encoder);
            encoder.flush();
            byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
            out.close();
            return bytes;
        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error serializing Avro message", e);
        }
    }
```

Deserializer :

```
protected T deserialize(Schema schema, byte[] payload) throws SerializationException {
        // Even if the caller requests schema & version, if the payload is null
        // cannot include it. The caller must handle
        // this case.
        if (payload == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int id = -1;
        try {
            ByteBuffer buffer = getByteBuffer(payload);
            id = buffer.getInt();
            int length = buffer.limit() - 1 - 4;

            int start = buffer.position() + buffer.arrayOffset();
            DatumReader<T> reader = new ReflectDatumReader<T>(schema);
            T res = reader.read(null, new DecoderFactory().binaryDecoder(buffer.array(), start, length, null));
            return res;
        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error deserializing Avro message for id " + id, e);
        }
    }

    private ByteBuffer getByteBuffer(byte[] payload) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(payload);
        if (buffer.get() != 0x0) {
            throw new SerializationException("Unknown magic byte!");
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: "checking some online tutorial" -> can you include the link?

Comment: Details on how to send Avro serialised messages are here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#serializer

Comment: @RobinMoffatt i tried finding online link  , but was unable to recollect

Comment: @RobinMoffatt  can you please point me to the doc containing text about usage of Avro serializer for custom POJO

Comment: The schema registry documentation that's already linked to should include that, but that's assuming you are actually using the Confluent Schema Registry, and not plain Avro encoded bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For serializing I am using ReflectDatumWriter . Before sending the bytes[] I am putting schema ID in first 4 bytes with schema ID

Not clear why you are trying to [bypass the `KafkaAvroSerializer` class's default behavior](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#serializer). (In your case, remove `Schema.Parser` from that example, and use your Reflect record type rather than `GenericRecord`)

You can put your concrete class as the second type of the producer and as long as it implements the base Avro classes, it should be serialized correctly (meaning ID computed correctly, not some number you create, and converted to bytes), registered to the registry, then sent to Kafka

Most importantly, the schema ID is not necessarily a 1 in the registry, and by putting that, the console consumer might be trying to deserialize your messages incorrectly, resulting in the wrong output

In other words, try

```
ProducerRecord<String, MParams> record = new ProducerRecord<>(...)
```

Comment: I ended up removing bytes transformation with schema ID    which was not the right approach . I used ProducerRecord initialisation the way you suggested with a generic custom deserializer for value using DatumWriter

Comment: Why do you need a custom deserializer?

Comment: Because my producer sources have different types and can evolve with time . Internally they are using generics in design hence a custom deserializer was required . Not sure if KafkaAvroDeserializer can just do this

Comment: Avro can already evolve over time within the context of a single object class. The subjects in the schema registry store multiple versions, and backwards compatibility is enforced by default across all versions of a single subject/topic

Comment: I will be having multiple object classes , is versioning valid for this case ?

Comment: Versions would still be applied for each object type. Feel free to read over this blog post - https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/

Comment: And if you really needed Generics, you could use `ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord>`, and similarly on the consumer side. From there, you can check if statements on the Avro data's namespaces and types

Comment: I have added serializer and deseralizer class's methods for an insight . might not be the case of re using the wheel but I will defniately check out Generic Recrods

Comment: `RefectData` is a specific implementation of `SpecificRecord`, which extends `GenericRecord` https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/ReflectData.html